# E/Go: fatal error: thread exhaustion

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, android, aar

I am experimenting with the geth-android library with [light-client and in-process node from @karalabe](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile-Clients:-Libraries-and-Inproc-Ethereum-Nodes). I could successfully sync with the testnet node from @phonikg, unfortunately this one is down now. When trying to sync with the main-net I am running into a thread exaustion :-(

I think this might be a consequence of the recent attacks. Unfortunately, I found no documentation on how to compile the geth aar for a in-process node. It might be as easy as to know in which branch I have to "make geth-android"

```
E/GoLog: I1010 20:43:50.405850 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1187] Rolled back 2048 headers (LH: 2320767->2318719, FB: 0->0, LB: 0->0)
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1426(44KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 36% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 11.401ms total 49.432ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3271(116KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 37% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 35.760ms total 74.242ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1530(47KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 34% free, 6MB/10MB, paused 13.371ms total 54.076ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3665(129KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 20.665ms total 110.587ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1432(44KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 34% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 16.343ms total 60.553ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3654(158KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 34% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 16.432ms total 75.361ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1617(50KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 20.499ms total 79.020ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3688(131KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 25.847ms total 122.223ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1515(47KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 8MB/12MB, paused 21.154ms total 87.873ms
E/Go: runtime: program exceeds 10000-thread limit
E/Go: fatal error: thread exhaustion
E/Go: runtime stack:
E/Go: runtime.throw(0x7f39787cd2ef, 0x11)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95
E/Go: runtime.checkmcount()
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/proc.go:486 +0xa4
E/Go: runtime.mcommoninit(0xc43f92b400)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/proc.go:506 +0xd5
E/Go: runtime.allocm(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1286 +0x9b
E/Go: runtime.oneNewExtraM()
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1419 +0x37
E/Go: runtime.newextram()
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1407 +0x9e
E/Go: runtime.systemstack(0x7f36e1ea0848)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:298 +0x79
E/Go: runtime.mstart()
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1079
E/Go: goroutine 80292 [running, locked to thread]:
E/Go: runtime.systemstack_switch()
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 fp=0xc453bc4eb0 sp=0xc453bc4ea8
E/Go: runtime.cgocallbackg1(0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:182 +0x5d fp=0xc453bc4f28 sp=0xc453bc4eb0
E/Go: runtime.cgocallbackg(0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:170 +0x84 fp=0xc453bc4f90 sp=0xc453bc4f28
E/Go: runtime.cgocallback_gofunc(0x0, 0x2c1, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:728 +0x74 fp=0xc453bc4fb0 sp=0xc453bc4f90
E/Go: runtime.goexit()
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1 fp=0xc453bc4fb8 sp=0xc453bc4fb0
E/Go: goroutine 22 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc420118000)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x247
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x1bc
E/Go: goroutine 17 [select, locked to thread]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc.(*requestOp).wait(0xc42c53bf40, 0x7f39777a4280, 0xc42000c578, 0xc42c53bf40, 0x7f3978ab5300, 0xc42bc0dd50)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/client.go:138 +0x197
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc.(*Client).CallContext(0xc428446e00, 0x7f39777a4280, 0xc42000c578, 0x7f3978aefd00, 0xc42c7b9940, 0x7f39787c196a, 0xe, 0xc42c7b9960, 0x2, 0x2, ...)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/client.go:267 +0x23e
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient.(*Client).BalanceAt(0xc4286a8820, 0x7f39777a4280, 0xc42000c578, 0x90379a05c9ef2fe8, 0x7b221506e3bd1ef2, 0xc45e64ad42, 0xc42c7b9920, 0x1, 0x7f3978aa9e00, 0xc4ffffff01)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient/ethclient.go:239 +0x1cb
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/mobile.(*EthereumClient).GetBalanceAt(0xc4286a8828, 0xc4203a1f40, 0xc4265398c0, 0x234dee, 0xffffecf1, 0x5, 0x1)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/mobile/ethclient.go:151 +0x186
E/Go: _/tmp/gomobile-work-083702378/gomobile_bind.proxygeth_EthereumClient_GetBalanceAt(0xffffffe8ffffecf2, 0x7f39ffffecf1, 0x234dee, 0xc4261a7eb0)
E/Go:   /tmp/gomobile-work-083702378/gomobile_bind/go_gethmain.go:1288 +0xf1
E/Go: _/tmp/gomobile-work-083702378/gomobile_bind._cgoexpwrap_54baf865da9d_proxygeth_EthereumClient_GetBalanceAt(0xffffffe8ffffecf2, 0x7f39ffffecf1, 0x234dee, 0x12ffa130)
E/Go:   ??:0 +0x43
E/Go: goroutine 18 [select, locked to thread]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc.(*requestOp).wait(0xc421c1db00, 0x7f39777a4280, 0xc42000c578, 0xc421c1db00, 0x7f3978ab5300, 0xc427c60540)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/client.go:138 +0x197
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc.(*Client).CallContext(0xc426ca47e0, 0x7f39777a4280, 0xc42000c578, 0x7f3978aefd00, 0xc422c39be0, 0x7f39787c196a, 0xe, 0xc422c39c00, 0x2, 0x2, ...)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/client.go:267 +0x23e
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient.(*Client).BalanceAt(0xc4286a9320, 0x7f39777a4280, 0xc42000c578, 0x90379a05c9ef2fe8, 0x7b221506e3bd1ef2, 0xc45e64ad42, 0xc422c39bc0, 0x1, 0x7f3978aa9e00, 0xc4ffffff01)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient/ethclient.go:239 +0x1cb
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/mobile.(*EthereumClient).GetBalanceAt(0xc4286a9328, 0xc4203a1f40, 0xc4265ca5a0, 0x234e1e, 0xffffecd8, 0x5, 0x1)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/mobile/ethclient.go:151 +0x186
E/Go: _/tmp/gomobile-work-083702378/gomobile_bind.proxygeth_EthereumClient_GetBalanceAt(0xffffffe8ffffecdb, 0x7f39ffffecd8, 0x234e1e, 0xc422733eb0)
E/Go:   /tmp/gomobile-work-083702378/gomobile_bind/go_gethmain.go:1288 +0xf1
E/Go: _/tmp/gomobile-work-083702378/gomobile_bind._cgoexpwrap_54baf865da9d_proxygeth_EthereumClient_GetBalanceAt(0xffffffe8ffffecdb, 0x7f39ffffecd8, 0x234e1e, 0x1302f110)
E/Go:   ??:0 +0x43
E/Go: goroutine 5 [syscall]:
E/Go: syscall.Syscall(0x0, 0x14, 0xc420092000, 0x400, 0x7d, 0x400, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s:18 +0x5
E/Go: syscall.read(0x14, 0xc420092000, 0x400, 0x400, 0x7d, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_amd64.go:783 +0x55
E/Go: syscall.Read(0x14, 0xc420092000, 0x400, 0x400, 0x7d, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go:161 +0x49
E/Go: os.(*File).read(0xc42001e020, 0xc420092000, 0x400, 0x400, 0xc420001df8, 0x300000002, 0x7f397812a010)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/os/file_unix.go:228 +0x4f
E/Go: os.(*File).Read(0xc42001e020, 0xc420092000, 0x400, 0x400, 0x200000003, 0x1, 0x7f3978125cb1)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/os/file.go:101 +0x59
E/Go: bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc42001bef0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x10c
E/Go: bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice(0xc42001bef0, 0x7f39780fcc0a, 0xc426f25000, 0xc42001be58, 0xc400000004, 0x42001be48, 0xc426f25000)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:330 +0xb5
E/Go: bufio.(*Reader).ReadLine(0xc42001bef0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f38bdabfc00, 0x7c, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:359 +0x37
E/Go: golang.org/x/mobile/internal/mobileinit.lineLog(0xc42001e020, 0x6)
E/Go:   /work/src/golang.org/x/mobile/internal/mobileinit/mobileinit_android.go:50 +0xa5
E/Go: created by golang.org/x/mobile/internal/mobileinit.init.1
E/Go:   /work/src/golang.org/x/mobile/internal/mobileinit/mobileinit_android.go:74 +0xd2
E/Go: goroutine 6 [syscall, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: syscall.Syscall(0x0, 0x16, 0xc420052800, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s:18 +0x5
E/Go: syscall.read(0x16, 0xc420052800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_amd64.go:783 +0x55
E/Go: syscall.Read(0x16, 0xc420052800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go:161 +0x49
E/Go: os.(*File).read(0xc42001e030, 0xc420052800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/os/file_unix.go:228 +0x4f
E/Go: os.(*File).Read(0xc42001e030, 0xc420052800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x7f397810a8ce, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/os/file.go:101 +0x59
E/Go: bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc42001c6f0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x10c
E/Go: bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice(0xc42001c6f0, 0xa, 0x0, 0xc42001c648, 0x7f397813bbeb, 0x400, 0x7f3978a47720)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:330 +0xb5
E/Go: bufio.(*Reader).ReadLine(0xc42001c6f0, 0x400, 0x400, 0xc420052800, 0x400, 0x400, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:359 +0x37
E/Go: golang.org/x/mobile/internal/mobileinit.lineLog(0xc42001e030, 0x4)
E/Go:   /work/src/golang.org/x/mobile/internal/mobileinit/mobileinit_android.go:50 +0xa5
E/Go: created by golang.org/x/mobile/internal/mobileinit.init.1
E/Go:   /work/src/golang.org/x/mobile/internal/mobileinit/mobileinit_android.go:81 +0x12a
E/Go: goroutine 7 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/logger.dispatchLoop()
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/logger/sys.go:81 +0x636
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/logger.init.1
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/logger/sys.go:60 +0x35
E/Go: goroutine 8 [chan receive]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/logger/glog.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x7f3978fa09e0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/logger/glog/glog.go:931 +0x7a
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/logger/glog.init.1
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/logger/glog/glog.go:460 +0x83
E/Go: goroutine 9 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*nonrecursiveTree).dispatch(0xc420068300, 0xc420068240)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/tree_nonrecursive.go:36 +0x5a
E/Go: created by github.com/rjeczalik/notify.newNonrecursiveTree
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/tree_nonrecursive.go:29 +0x181
E/Go: goroutine 10 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*nonrecursiveTree).internal(0xc420068300, 0xc4200682a0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/tree_nonrecursive.go:81 +0x94
E/Go: created by github.com/rjeczalik/notify.newNonrecursiveTree
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/tree_nonrecursive.go:30 +0x1ad
E/Go: goroutine 11 [syscall, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:116 +0x157
E/Go: os/signal.loop()
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x22
E/Go: created by os/signal.init.1
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x41
E/Go: goroutine 24 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc420336000)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:97 +0x15d
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x642
E/Go: goroutine 23 [select, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc420336000)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0x5e1
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:141 +0x620
E/Go: goroutine 25 [select, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc420336000)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:804 +0x83c
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:148 +0x7c8
E/Go: goroutine 37 [IO wait]:
E/Go: net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f3976ca4f00, 0x72, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160 +0x59
E/Go: net.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc420422060, 0x72, 0xc42040bc30, 0xc42000c0a0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x38
E/Go: net.(*pollDesc).waitRead(0xc420422060, 0x7f3978ef7300, 0xc42000c0a0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x34
E/Go: net.(*netFD).readFrom(0xc420422000, 0xc420398140, 0xc, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f3978ef7300, 0xc42000c0a0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:270 +0x1e9
E/Go: net.(*UDPConn).readFrom(0xc42039a028, 0xc420398140, 0xc, 0xc, 0x2, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/udpsock_posix.go:43 +0x6a
E/Go: net.(*UDPConn).ReadFromUDP(0xc42039a028, 0xc420398140, 0xc, 0xc, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc4222d9d60)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/udpsock.go:85 +0x75
E/Go: github.com/jackpal/go-nat-pmp.(*Client).rpc(0xc4203966c0, 0xc42040bf06, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc, 0xc420398140, 0xc, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/jackpal/go-nat-pmp/natpmp.go:138 +0x283
E/Go: github.com/jackpal/go-nat-pmp.(*Client).GetExternalAddress(0xc4203966c0, 0xc4203966c0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/jackpal/go-nat-pmp/natpmp.go:62 +0x73
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/nat.discoverPMP.func1(0xc420398104, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc4203fc060)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/nat/natpmp.go:73 +0x6c
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/nat.discoverPMP
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/nat/natpmp.go:78 +0xd2
E/Go: goroutine 59 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc.(*Client).dispatch(0xc4202d6380, 0x7f3978f016e0, 0xc4217ac130)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/client.go:490 +0xcc7
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc.newClient
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/rpc/client.go:203 +0x3fd
E/Go: goroutine 14 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc420118e00)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x247
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x1bc
E/Go: goroutine 53 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc420337500)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0x5e1
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:141 +0x620
E/Go: goroutine 54 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc420337500)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:97 +0x15d
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x642
E/Go: goroutine 55 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc420337500)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:804 +0x83c
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:148 +0x7c8
E/Go: goroutine 56 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc420337500)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:751 +0x263
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x7ea
E/Go: goroutine 57 [select, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).jWriter(0xc420337500)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_write.go:37 +0x1ad
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x80c
E/Go: goroutine 67 [runnable]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/cache.(*Cache).getBucket(0xc4203cd2c0, 0xca022bda, 0xc400000f00, 0x7f39ca022bda)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/cache/cache.go:316
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/cache.(*Cache).Get(0xc4203cd2c0, 0xb, 0x200473, 0xc42bbb1348, 0x0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/cache/cache.go:377 +0xb8
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/cache.(*NamespaceGetter).Get(0xc436b39440, 0x200473, 0xc42bbb1348, 0x40)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/cache/cache.go:58 +0x4b
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table.(*Reader).readFilterBlockCached(0xc4379ba5b0, 0x200473, 0x7ef5, 0xc443a46d01, 0x2, 0x4700, 0x99d, 0x2, 0x184979)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table/reader.go:686 +0xf0
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table.(*Reader).getFilterBlock(0xc4379ba5b0, 0x1, 0x4703, 0x184979, 0x99d, 0x5, 0xc446ab4870)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table/reader.go:715 +0xce
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table.(*Reader).find(0xc4379ba5b0, 0xc433def180, 0x12, 0x12, 0x7f3978124e01, 0x0, 0x7f397842f400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table/reader.go:842 +0x7dd
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table.(*Reader).Find(0xc4379ba5b0, 0xc433def180, 0x12, 0x12, 0x1, 0x0, 0x12, 0x1, 0xc42bbb1610, 0xc42bbb15d0, ...)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table/reader.go:888 +0x7a
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*tOps).find(0xc42044c8d0, 0xc42bc4b540, 0xc433def180, 0x12, 0x12, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/table.go:382 +0x1f1
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*version).get.func1(0x1, 0xc42bc4b540, 0xa)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/version.go:167 +0x4f1
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*version).walkOverlapping(0xc42bc4b400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc433def180, 0x12, 0x12, 0xc42bbb1890, 0xc42bbb1860)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/version.go:120 +0x49c
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*version).get(0xc42bc4b400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc433def180, 0x12, 0x12, 0x0, 0x3fff00, 0x0, ...)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/version.go:221 +0x2ae
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).get(0xc420337500, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc43607f080, 0xa, 0x10, 0x155e7, 0x0, ...)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:774 +0x2af
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).Get(0xc420337500, 0xc43607f080, 0xa, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:840 +0x198
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethdb.(*LDBDatabase).Get(0xc420884180, 0xc43607f080, 0xa, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethdb/database.go:127 +0xb2
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.GetCanonicalHash(0x7f3978eff760, 0xc420884180, 0x80af9, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/database_util.go:73 +0x1cc
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/light.(*TxPool).setNewHead(0xc4208840c0, 0x7f3976cab888, 0xc424738ae0, 0xc424727440, 0xc424738ae0, 0xc424a177e0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/light/txpool.go:278 +0x87b
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/light.(*TxPool).eventLoop(0xc4208840c0)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/light/txpool.go:307 +0x18a
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/light.NewTxPool
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/light/txpool.go:95 +0x40c
E/Go: goroutine 68 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*Downloader).qosTuner(0xc421891500)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:1465 +0x384
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.New
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:204 +0xf5c
E/Go: goroutine 69 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/les.(*lightFetcher).syncLoop(0xc420094700)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/les/fetcher.go:239 +0x64d
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/les.newLightFetcher
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/les/fetcher.go:72 +0x285
E/Go: goroutine 70 [select, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/nat.Map(0x7f3978efe540, 0xc4203cca80, 0xc420069140, 0x7f39787b241f, 0x3, 0xa5ba, 0xa5ba, 0x7f39787ce6c8, 0x12)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/nat/nat.go:114 +0x80b
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover.newUDP
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover/udp.go:232 +0x551
E/Go: goroutine 26 [select, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc420336000)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:751 +0x263
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x7ea
E/Go: goroutine 27 [select, 1 minutes]:
E/Go: github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).jWriter(0xc420336000)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_write.go:37 +0x1ad
E/Go: created by github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x80c
E/Go: goroutine 28 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover.(*Table).refreshLoop(0xc420150900)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover/table.go:327 +0x4cd
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover.newTable
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover/table.go:117 +0x407
E/Go: goroutine 29 [select]:
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover.(*udp).loop(0xc42032e310)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover/udp.go:361 +0x999
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover.newUDP
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover/udp.go:247 +0x394
E/Go: goroutine 30 [IO wait]:
E/Go: net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f3976ca4cc0, 0x72, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160 +0x59
E/Go: net.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc42032e300, 0x72, 0xc4586b9d98, 0xc42000c0a0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x38
E/Go: net.(*pollDesc).waitRead(0xc42032e300, 0x7f3978ef7300, 0xc42000c0a0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x34
E/Go: net.(*netFD).readFrom(0xc42032e2a0, 0xc420330500, 0x500, 0x500, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f3978ef7300, 0xc42000c0a0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:270 +0x1e9
E/Go: net.(*UDPConn).readFrom(0xc42039a090, 0xc420330500, 0x500, 0x500, 0x7f, 0xc4586b9ee8, 0x7f397824bef1, 0x7f3978a80600)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/udpsock_posix.go:43 +0x6a
E/Go: net.(*UDPConn).ReadFromUDP(0xc42039a090, 0xc420330500, 0x500, 0x500, 0x500, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
E/Go:   /opt/google/go/src/net/udpsock.go:85 +0x75
E/Go: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover.(*udp).readLoop(0xc42032e310)
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover/udp.go:497 +0xd5
E/Go: created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover.newUDP
E/Go:   /work/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/discover/udp.go:248 +0x3b9
E/Go: goroutine 31 [IO wait, 1 minutes]:
```

Answer (score 0):

**I see three different possibilities here:**

1. that the most likely cause is that you are not running a light
   client and therefore are not able to sync with the main net. Try
   running a light client instead.
2. The issue is caused by the change in the main-net that happened
   recently. You need to recompile the geth aar for a in-process node.
3. It could be that your phone is not able to connect to the main
   net. Try using a different phone or a different network.

Answer (score 0):

show some code will be better. now I can't just guess by the error.

pls check your setting at beginning:

```
// Start the geth-android node with the --min-peers and --max-peers options set to a low value
Geth.run("--min-peers", "5", "--max-peers", "10");
```